# Breeze create entity, update locally

Tags: breeze

I have a list of test objects that are displayed on my page, I would like to be able to add new entities to this list using breeze.

The first thing that I do is prime the current data from the server using the following code:

```
var getTestObjects = function (testObjects) {
        var query = EntityQuery.from('TestObject');

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {

            if (testObjects) {
                testObjects(data.results);
            }
            datacontext.testObjects = getLocal('TestObject');
        };
    };

function getLocal(resource) {
        var query = EntityQuery.from(resource);
        return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
}
```

Next I call the Create method for the object:

```
var createTestObject = function (initialValues) {
        var testObjectType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("TestObject");
        var newTestObject = testObjectType.createEntity(initialValues);
        return manager.addEntity(newTestObject);
    };

datacontext.createTestObject({ name: 'test' });
datacontext.saveChanges();
```

All this works fine and the entity is added to the database, however when I call `datacontext.testObjects` (the locally available entities), it doesn't have the newly added item. Should this be available or do I have to get the data from the server again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datacontext is not an instance of any Breeze type so I have no idea what your 'datacontext.textobjects' is.  But... if you want all of the local entities in an entityManager simply call *EntityManager.getEntities()*;  So in your example use:

```
var localEntities = manager.getEntities();
```

For more info see: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_getEntities

Comment: Also to create a new entity OP should use manager.createEntity('EntityName', { properties });

Comment: Actually, if testObjectType is an EntityType, then calling the EntityType.createEntity method should be fine. http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityType.html#method_createEntity

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer - datacontext is my viewmodel, so datacontext.textobjects was calling manager.executeQueryLocally. Didn't realise that getEntities existed! Thank you so much!